# How can I count the number of elements each key holds in an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I am trying to update the variable `$numberOfFoods` in a foreach loop with the number of elements that each key holds in an associative array. Here is my code:

```
$foodsArray = array (
        'France' => ['Souffle' , 'Baguette' , 'Fois gras'],
        'England' => ['Bangers and mash' , 'Tea and biscuits'],
        'America' => ['Hamburger', 'Steak and Eggs', 'Texas chili']
    );
    $countriesByCuisine = array();       

    foreach ($foodsArray as $originCountry => $countryAssocFood) {
        $numberOfFoods = count(array_values($foodsArray));
        for ($countryAssocFoodIndex = 0; $countryAssocFoodIndex < $numberOfFoods; $countryAssocFoodIndex++) {
            $countriesByCuisine[$countryAssocFood[$countryAssocFoodIndex]] = $originCountry;
        }
    }

    foreach (array_keys($countriesByCuisine) as $foodFromCountry) {
        echo $foodFromCountry . ', From '  . $countriesByCuisine[$foodFromCountry] . '. ';
    }
```

As it is, this code simply sets the `$numberOfFoods` variable to the integer 3, rather than updating the number to reflect the number of values that the current key holds. My overall goal with this code was to learn how to transform an array such that the values become keys in a new array, with those keys holding their previous keys as values. Please forgive my messy code, as I am pretty new to programming and PHP.

Comment: `array_flip` will do that for you

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like the result to look like?

Comment: My original goal (which was met by the suggestion to make `$numberOfFoods = count(array_values($countryAssocFood));` , would transform `$foodsArray = array (
        'France' => ['Souffle' , 'Baguette' , 'Fois gras'],
        'England' => ['Bangers and mash' , 'Tea and biscuits'],
        'America' => ['Hamburger', 'Steak and Eggs', 'Texas chili']`  into `$countriesByCuisine = array('Souffle' => 'France', 'Baguette' => 'France');` etc etc for all former values of `$foodsArray` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Robbie Averill is right about `array_flip` to achieve you "overall goal" of flipping the keys and the values.

There are multiple, more efficient, ways to fix your current code, the best one probably being `array_map`, but I also want to provide you with why your current code is failing:

The issue is that you are counting `$foodsArray` for each iteration (and it's always equal to 3), instead of counting `$countryAssocFood`:

`$numberOfFoods = count(array_values($countryAssocFood));`

Comment: That's not what I understodd from the way he phrased the question. He starts by saying what he wants to do (update the variable $numberOfFoods in a foreach loop with the number of elements that each key holds), then shows the code, then says that the current does ( this code simply sets the $numberOfFoods variable to the integer 3).
Seems to me that fixing the count is what he wants. He can always ignore my answer if it wasn't.

Comment: :D we don't what he wants

Comment: I appreciate the response. To clarify, the assignment `$numberOfFoods = count(array_values($countryAssocFood));` does accomplish the change I was looking for. I hadn't grokked that I was working with an array assigned to each key, so I didn't even consider using the array_values function on `$countryAssocFood`. I would also be interested in learning whether array_flip has an identical result, as I had considered using it before I decided to learn how to transform the array iteratively. I'll mess around with that and array_map in the meantime.

Comment: In case it proves any closure for @Chinito, you were correct that I had understood the problem with my count method, but my issue was that I had failed to see that the answer was a relatively obvious change to my usage of `array_values`.